# Make form responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form inside of jumbotron and for some reason I get it to look good on desktop view but when viewing it mobile it goes out of the jumbotron. I am using netbeans to do my coding. I even use @media (max-width: 620px). I tried using google but failed :(

```css
    #wrapper{
        width: 500px;
        height: 700px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        text-align: center;
        
    }
    form{
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
       
    }
    div{
       clear: both;
    }
    #off{
        background-color: rgba(225,0,0,.85);
        color: white;
        width: 525px;
        height: 140px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .formHeader{
        color: #104c8b;
    }
    .formFooter{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
        color: white;
        margin: 65px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 620px) {
       
        #wrapper{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        text-align: center;
        
    }
```

```html
    <section id="top" class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div id="wrapper"><p>Contact Form</p>
                        <div class="formHeader">
                            
                        </div>
                <form action="test.html" method="get" name="test" id="myForm">
                    <label>Name</label><input name="name" type="text" /><br>
                    <label>Email</label><input name="email" type="text" /><br>
                    <label>Phone</label><input name="number" type="text" /><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                </form>
                    <div class="formFooter">
                            
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Your wrapper element needs one or more of the col- classes

Comment: like <div id="wrapper" class="col-sm-6"></div>

Comment: Yes. You may need to specify multiple columns, depending on the screen sizes you're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using Bootstrap as a framework it seems a shame not to make use of all of well... the framework.  With some restructuring of your HTML (to make use of Bootstrap's responsive classes and form controls) you can easily achieve the responsiveness you desire.

Most of it is just adding the necessary `.col-*-*` for grid layouts, and of course applying Bootstrap classes to your `input` and `label` elements, etc.  An example Bootply is below though the code is significantly altered to better-reflect Bootstrap's Framework and modern input classifications (like `tel` or `email`, etc).

http://www.bootply.com/mPNCZyXbbD

The HTML:

```
<section id="top" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="form-wrapper text-center">
          <p>Contact Form</p>

          <form action="test.html" method="get" name="test" id="myForm" class="form form-horizontal">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input name="number" type="tel" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.form-wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code from bootply (or just the relevant bits) in your answer?

Comment: Just updated to reflect the actual code- though it seems more an education into the Bootstrap Framework than something particularly relevant / useful as a solution.

Comment: I have added what you edited and the form works but when I put it to mobile view it shows that it is coming out of the jumbotron/background picture. Would I need to edit the bootstrap class'es in css to make it fit more properly?

Comment: @ctapn1307 - The code I provided should not be added to your code; it overwrites it entirely.  The `.form-wrapper` class I have functions the same as your `#wrapper` with the exception that it is responsive.

Comment: @Robert C
Could you show me how to do an image behind the form... I have tried this way that you showed but it does not display correctly when going to mobile the form is coming out of the jumbotron then I have tried other steps to make it work but I am not sure if it is able to be done.

Comment: You could just specify a background image inside the `.form-wrapper`.  If you're having issues where the form is extending beyond code outside what I've presented, you may need to pose that as a new question.